# C#, is this "if... else..." block equivalent to one line of code using null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, null-coalescing-operator

I'm curious if this block of code:

```
//value is an object, maybe null, maybe not
if (value == null)
   item.PassageStimuliTitle = "";
else
   item.PassageStimuliTitle = value.ToString().Trim();
```

is equivalent to this line:

```
item.PassageStimuliTitle = (string)(value ?? value.ToString().Trim());
```

I've used if... else... for a long time, but recently came across the null-coalescing operator in C#.  I've used it to prevent null exception errors for params passed in method calls.  I think using it in the example above is equivalent, and condenses the code from 4 lines to 1.  Thanks for reading.  Curious to hear feedback.

I'm expecting the two examples to be equivalent, but curious if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Those do not appear equivalent to my eyes. The second one looks like a guaranteed null reference exception if `value` is `null`. Fewest lines of code is rarely a good metric for measuring code quality and keeping code that *clearly* expresses what you want is probably better than condensing down to one broken line.

Comment: You really can't do what you want with `??` here.

Comment: You can maybe do it with a null-conditional operator: `value?.ToString().Trim() ?? ""`

Comment: Charles, ah right. I think you need two, though: `value?.ToString()?.Trim() ?? ""`

Comment: @xanadont would depend if your `ToString()` implementation could return `null`. I'd hope it wouldn't.

Comment: `?.ToString()` would.

Comment: @xanadont no, `Trim` wouldn't get executed because `value` was null (so `ToString` never got executed). See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mMmj9x). You would only need the second null-conditional if `ToString` could return `null`, and [the guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0#notes-to-inheritors) is that it shouldn't (but ultimately depends on your implementation).

Comment: Hey, yep, just did the same fiddle. Nice.

Answer (score 6):

No, the null-coalescing operator expression is not written correctly. `a ?? b` means "evaluate to `b` if `a` is null, otherwise evaluate to `a`". Therefore, your use of the null-coalescing operator will always produce a `NullReferenceException` if `value` is null - your code will try to evaluate `value.ToString()` when `value` is null.

Your use of `??` would translate to something like the following if statement, which I think you'd agree is quite non-sensical:

```
if (value == null) {
    item.PassageStimuliTitle = (string)value.ToString().Trim();
} else {
    item.PassageStimuliTitle = (string)value;
}
```

With certain assumptions, the if statement can be rewritten as:

```
item.PassageStimuliTitle = value?.ToString().Trim() ?? "";
```

This uses the [null conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). If `value` is null, then the entire `value?.ToString().Trim()` expression is null, and hence the RHS of the `??` is evaluated. Otherwise, `.ToString().Trim()` is called on `value`.

Comment: `?.` not required after `ToString()`

Comment: @OkanKaradag You're right. I've been writing too much Kotlin, where this is needed, and has written that habitually. (lol)

Answer (score 0):

`item.PassageStimuliTitle = value != null ? value.ToString().Trim() : "";`

From @Charles Mager comment:

`item.PassageStimuliTitle = value?.ToString().Trim() ?? ""`

Is a better and clearer one-liner.

Comment: I think this would be cleaner if it made use of `?.`

Answer (score -1):

You used ?? operator incorrectly.
In this example:

```
result = left_value ?? right_value;
```

?? operator returns left_value if it is NOT null.
If left_value is null, it returns right_value.

So, in your case, if variable value is of type **object**, it should be:

```
item.PassageStimuliTitle = (value ?? "").ToString().Trim();
```

Here is a successfully compiled code [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yw0OIC).

Comment: That won't work, `value` isn't a `string`

Comment: Yes, value is not a string. What is your problem? Value is checked for not null with ?? and if it is not null, we take it and convert with .ToString().

Comment: Because you can't coalesce an arbitrary null object to a string - the types won't match.

Comment: @CharlesMager And the author asked about using ?? operator. Not about using ? : operator. So your comment above is incorrect.

Comment: I've not downvoted. But your code will not compile unless the type of `value` is either `string` or `object`. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CA7Cix).

Comment: @CharlesMager I used "value.ToString().Trim();" from authors QUESTION. Just to show him his error.

Comment: Yes, that works. But if `value` is type `Foo` then `value ?? ""` won't compile. It works if the type is `string` or `object`, but I guess we don't actually know the types here.

Comment: @CharlesMager We know for sure, read the question carefully: "//value is an object, maybe null, maybe not".

Comment: Everything is an object, I hadn't interpreted that as the actual static type of `value`. But it's possible it is.

Comment: *Compilation error (line 8, col 15): Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Foo' and 'string'*? I'm not going to continue this discussion, I've explained the circumstances in which this can and cannot work. I don't have anything more to add.

Comment: It's the same link?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yw0OIC

Comment: This is new fiddle. Looks like my changes in your fiddle cannot be saved :(

Comment: So this shows that it only works if the type is `object` (or `string`)... which is what I've, evidently unsuccessfully, been trying to explain. I think we're done here.

Comment: The author of a question said clearly, that value is of type object. Have a nice day.